# How to increase the code view box size of ChatGPT web interface

Tags: openai-api

It is frustrating how small the code viewing is in ChatGPT and to make the matters worse it has a fixed width that does not change with the size of the browser window.

A temporary solution is this bookmarklet to maximize all the elements:

Create a bookmark and put this in the URL. Then run by selecting the bookmark on ChatGPT UI.

```
javascript:(function() { 
  document.querySelectorAll('div[class*="group w-full"] > div > div')
    .forEach((element) => { element.className = "flex flex-1"; }); 
})();
```

Is there a better solution than this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if you consider this a better solution, but an alternative to the javascript code is using custom CSS. For example, the following CSS code will make the chat occupy the whole screen:

```
.text-base {
    max-width: 100% !important;
    padding-left: 20px !important;
    padding-right: 20px !important;
}
```

You can apply custom CSS to a website with a browser extenstion, for example Stylebot. This way it's also easy to toggle it on/off.

More information on [this](https://community.openai.com/t/please-widen-the-code-block-style-element-in-chat/132308/3) forum.

Comment: Since it's somewhat related, I will post in this comment how to do the same thing for Gemini chatbot. Just replace `.text-base` with `.conversation-container`.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it's hard to find a permanent solution because that is up to the webmaster (openai). That said, the problem lies that the code is changed dinamically every time you start a new chat or go back to one in your history tab.

Therefore, you can change your bookmarket a little bit to run at an interval so that you don't need to click again over and over:

```
javascript:(function() { 
   var intervalId = setInterval(() => {
   document.querySelectorAll('div[class*="group w-full"] > div > div')
    .forEach((element) => { element.className = "flex flex-1"; }); 
}, 1000);})();
```

And if you need a more automatic solution, look for a chrome extension that allows you to append customized javascript, like [Tampermonkey](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo?hl=pt-BR).

Comment: ah. good idea to run it constantly. thanks :-)